# Bitbake/Yocto simple script tasks

Tags: bash, yocto, bitbake

I want to setup a bitbake recipe which runs a bash script uploading artifacts to aws. The recipe is small and looks like this:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Task for uploading build artifacts to aws"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
SECTION = "utils"

DEPENDS += "XXXXX-bundle-${AWS_DEPLOY_IMG_TYPE}"

UPLOAD_SCRIPT := "${THISDIR}/files/dev/aws-upload.sh"

do_build() {
        ${UPLOAD_SCRIPT}
}
```

But when trying to run the recipe:

```
bitbake bundle-aws-upload
```

I do not see anything happening. No errors, no nothing. The depedency bundle was build but the script did not execute as it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the log for the task, in `tmp/work/.../temp/log.do_build`.

The problem is probably that because you're not referring to `aws_upload.sh` in a SRC_URI  or any other dependencies, bitbake doesn't know you want to re-run the task.  Put `aws_upload.sh` in SRC_URI and invoke it directly from `WORKDIR`.

FYI, probably a better way of implementing that would be to have an image class you inherit (in `IMAGE_CLASSES`) that adds a new task `aws_upload`.

Comment: That was not the issue it turns out that the bitbake variables like "$MACHINE" and "$TMPDIR" are not passed to the child process $UPLOAD_SCRIPT. Is there a more elegant way to pass them down then modifying the bash script to take in 12 parameters?

Comment: Export them before calling the script.